# Get response using Jquery from a url

Tags: javascript, html, http, jquery

I am firing a GET request using jquery but not getting response what could be problem ?
Below is the html code. I am getting an alert showing

*Please anyone provide me some running example, in which should be using some well known website which i can also access like http://www.google.co.in or http://www.jlcindia.com*

> error:error

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<Script Language="JavaScript">

function getFullName(){
            //alert('fun call');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://www.jlcindia.com",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('success'+data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                if (textStatus !== null) {
                                    alert("error: " + textStatus);
                                } else if (errorThrown !== null) {
                                    alert("exception: " + errorThrown.message);
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert ("Don't know what is error");
                                }
                            }
                });               
        }
</Script>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Show Full Name" onClick="getFullName()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are any alerts coming up, ie. the "fun call" one.

Comment: Is this a crossDomain request?

Comment: 1. No i am not getting error <br>
2. No i am not getting alert even first one alert('fun call'); is also not coming<br>
3. I am not getting what u mean by cross domain request my web app is in same local area network

Comment: cross domain means, that you cannot call the page "example.de" in your Ajax call when your domain lies under "example.com" - it has nothing to do with your LAN.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a comma after the closing brace of 'success', immediately before "error".  Also, there are other issues with your code, ie you shouldn't put your ajax function in a document.ready block if it is going to be called on a button click.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, Both are separate application

Comment: After removing  document.ready  i am getting alert 'Error'
what could be problem ? how to i identify? can i use firebug to root cause this issue?

Comment: In the error get the message and error from the method. `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` then console.log out or alert the status and errorThrown. That should help

Comment: @AlexReynolds I changed as u suggested and i am getting textStatus as error, What could be the problem?

Comment: By the way [This URL](http://www.jlcindia.com/) is working so u can run and test my example if you have jquery library

Comment: dont forget to fix the typos. Script, Language, JavaScript... and your code doesnt have a `<head></head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an ajax request to a different domain. And that won't work due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Example:
your site is hosted on www.mydomain.com and you are trying to access www.otherdomain.com through ajax. This is not possible.

Ajax requests work only on the same domain as the hosted script.

Comment: Is it possible through plain java script? is there thing else odata or something which will give me result ?

Comment: @Arvind it's possible using jsonp, but only if the site supports it. Google jsonp for more info

Comment: Some browsers (Firefox, Chrome, others?) have support for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

If this is an internal tool, and your users are using suitable browsers, that might work.

Comment: If you want a site with CORS enabled, try this: http://graph.facebook.com/facebook-developers